# Customize the pages for community & Functionlaity for change Username/Password

Tags: visualforce, community

I've created a community, Public user can Register/login into community.

When Public user logged into community, salesforce provide the by default community landing page. Please check below Screenshot URL. 
http://prntscr.com/f3io4x

As per the  above screenshot, when user click on setting, he will see the different option as per the below screnshot URL. 
http://prntscr.com/f3ioo5

Security setting has standard functionality to change Username/Password for the logged in User.

Now, I've to replace the standard landing page with customized VF Page. 
My page will like below. 
[image]

further pages of community will be like same customized vf page.

Now in this  page can i write my custom functionality to change username/Password for logged in user.

is the way that I'm try to go, Is correct? Please suggest.

Comment: It's possible to have custom visualforce pages that handle login/passwords etc.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NickCook I'm trying to achieve that; Community public logged in user can able to change his Username/Password etc from customize Vf pages.

Comment: Are you using a template like Napili or visualforce and tabs for the community?

Comment: @DaveHumm yes I'm using Sf+Tab Templete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create the custom VF page to change the password. salesforce provide the `site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword)` method to change the Password. In controller of VF page we need to pass required parameter to `site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword)`. then community will change the password.

To change the username we can create a Vf page as required then create a logic in controller to update the USER record by assigning the newly Username. In this way we can change username.

you can refer the below link for site method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm